# Can I make a popup encouraging a different browser, if uses is using internet explorer?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, internet-explorer, popup

I'm working on the front end of an application using .Net/C# and JavaScript that is not optimized for Internet Explorer. Is there a way for the app to recognize if the user is using IE a trigger a popup for them to use a different browser?

Answer (score 0):

Use the below JavaScript Function

```
function msieversion() {

var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");

if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./))  // If Internet Explorer, return version number
{
    alert(parseInt(ua.substring(msie + 5, ua.indexOf(".", msie))));
}
else  // If another browser, return 0
{
    alert('otherbrowser');
}

return false;
}
```

The userAgent property returns the value of the user-agent header sent by the browser to the server. The value returned contains information about the name, version and platform of the browser. See More [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_nav_useragent.asp)

MSIE = The name for Internet Explorer inside of the header

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you so much for your help :)